# Command line alternative to Windows' taskkill.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, task, kill, taskkill

First off, please don't attack me if I am posting this in the wrong spot. That happened to me earlier on Server Fault and I don't need it happening again.

Anyway, I've been working on writing some batch scripts, and I need a good Command Line taskkill.exe alternative to kill a program before it executes another command. For example:

```
@echo off
echo Killing task . . . 
AltTaskKiller /IM calc.exe
if running calc.exe goto notkilled
echo Task killed . . .
pause
goto end

:notkilled
echo Task could not be killed . . . 
pause

:end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `taskkill`? (Also, yes, unfortunately all software requests are off-topic here, as well on every site in the Stack Exchange network.)

Comment: If losing dependence on Windows components is your priority then you should start by ridding yourself of `cmd.exe`. This would of course probably make a big difference to the answers you receive.

Comment: Ok, ok, I worded that wrong. I just want a program that, if the Task Manager is disabled, and/or `taskkill` is disabled, I can still close an application through a command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nircmd will do what you want (and much more)

```
nircmd.exe killprocess calc.exe
```

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: Hey! That's what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay this should do the same thing:

```dos
WMIC PROCESS WHERE Name="calc.exe" CALL Terminate
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Just one question, will this method still work if Task Manager & `taskkill` are disabled?

Comment: @ditheredtransparency, why don't you test that yourself.

Comment: Because my system does not have those disabled, but the one at my office does.